# Combine RSS feeds for android App?

Tags: android, rss

I am currently working on a mobile app where I want to be able to take say 4 RSS feeds and then combine them into one feed so that I can use them with BuzzBox SDK. I have setup BuzzBox and got it working with one feed but I think the inbuilt RSSTaskReader only accepts one take at a time so I can only use one RSS feed.

If someone could tell me how to either hook into some sort of API that will let me generate one RSS Feed from many or use BuzzBox's built in RssTaskReader with multiple RSS feeds that would be great as I am stuck on this at the moment :S

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could read the multiple RSS feeds with the use of [Rome](https://code.google.com/p/android-rome-feed-reader). And then combine the Entities to generate a new RSS feed.

Comment: Would this new combined rss be one I could then pass to BuzzBox to handle to notifications of new entries? Would you know of any examples or tutorials for combining entries?

Comment: When you read the RSS feed you can parse it to an Array. Multiple arrays can be combined to one. When combined you can output a new RSS feed. The RSS should be BuzzBox friendly since its just an RSS feed.

Comment: I have looked at ROME and although it looks good I cannot find any good examples of readind multiple feeds and merging them, do you know any? as the documentation it poor to :S I was thinking of looking into Yahoo pipes do you know if I could use that to achieve what I am looking for? Thanks

Comment: Create a Syndfeed from the RSS url. Extract the SyndEntry objects. Put those objects in a new collection and create a new RSS feed.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that and let you know the results :)